# SyntaxHighlighter uncompressed src/shCore.js not working

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I am playing with SyntaxHighlighter v3.0.83 the uncompressed shCore.js and when I use it will not work. It just outputs plain text with no styles.

I have edited the index.html that comes with the download from http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/. Only thing I have edited is the path to scripts/shCore.js to src/shCore.php

I have checked and all files are being loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello SyntaxHighlighter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/shCoreDefault.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>
</head>

<body style="background: white; font-family: Helvetica">

<h1>Hello SyntaxHighlighter</h1>
<pre class="brush: js;">
function helloSyntaxHighlighter()
{
    return "hi!";
}
</pre>

</html>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there's a script file, XRegExp.js, that's included in the packed version but missed when copying to the src folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Hello SyntaxHighlighter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/XRegExp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/shBrushJava.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/shCoreEclipse.css"/>
<link href="css/shThemeEclipse.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>
</head>

<body style="background: white; font-family: Helvetica">

<h1>Hello SyntaxHighlighter</h1>
<pre class="brush: java">
/**
* This util class is used to connect AD server to get users
*/
package com.thomsonreuters.spirit.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import reuters.pers.PERSException;
import reuters.pers.core.userproj.ActiveDirectoryMgr;

public class ActiveDirectoryUtil {

private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(ActiveDirectoryUtil.class);

/**
 * Get user info from AD server
 * @param filter
 */
private static List<Staff> getUsersByFilter(String filter, String domain,

</pre>

</html>
```